# what does this vim command mean? to1new and bo1new

Tags: vim

in command mode, to1new opens a window at top with one-line heigth,
and bo1new opens a window at bottom. The number 1 could also be other values.

But what do they literally refer to? Couldn't find any documents 
with `help to` or `help to1new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the abbreviated command of `:botright 1 new` or `:topleft 1 new`. Which creates a new window with size 1 either at the top or at the bottom right or the bottom left.
See the help at `:h :botright` `:h :topright` and `:h :new`

Comment: saw it in the 'windows' part of the documentation, thank you for the quick response.